# Unable to fetch the selected value of Fortune Wheel

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the Fortune Wheel in this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fortune_wheel). When I fling the wheel, it will spin and end but when it is done, I'm unable to fetch the value of the selection.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_fortune_wheel/flutter_fortune_wheel.dart';

class SpinawheelWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SpinawheelState();
}

class SpinawheelState extends State<SpinawheelWidget> {
  StreamController<int> selected = StreamController<int>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    selected.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = <String>[
      'item1',
      'item2',
      'item3',
      'item4',
      'item5',
      'item6',
    ];

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: FortuneWheel(
            physics: CircularPanPhysics(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              curve: Curves.decelerate,
            ),
            onFling: () {
              print('onFling');
              selected.add(1);
            },
            onAnimationStart: () {
              print('animation start');
            },
            onAnimationEnd: () {
              print('animation end ${selected.stream}');
            },
            animateFirst: false,
            selected: selected.stream,
            items: [
              for (var it in items) FortuneItem(child: Text(it)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The print on onAnimationEnd only shows: **animation end** ***Instance of '_ControllerStream'*** but not the value. I am expect to get at least one of the item or the position of the item. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work. Just need some changes.
Change your declaration of stream controller to broadcast

```
StreamController<int> _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
```

Then the trick. In some place of your widget tree (mine was just above the FortuneWheel in a Column) insert this StreamBuilder. This will show nothing, just handle some functions. In order to let us handle the snapshot result, we wil add the _text funciontion returning a widget. See bellow:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: _controller.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
              ? _text(snapshot)
              : Container(),
        )
```

And now, the function returning the widget _text.

```
Widget _text(var snapshot) {
  //here you cand get and handle the result and do whathever.
  print(snapshot.data);
  int val = snapshot.data;
  print(items[val]);
  
  return Text(snapshot.data.toString()); //you dont need to return //anything here.  Just replace the Text widget with SizedBox() to return //nothing.
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the stream controller like this

```
StreamController<int> _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
```

then call the listen whatever you want , suggesting use listener inside initState function

```
_controller.stream.listen((value) {
      print('Value from controller: $value');
    })
```

Comment: please find the answer @Mr. Tacio

Answer (score 1):

As, the library is using Stream you will need to use stream method to get data from selection.One such method is called listen()

Rest you can check this : [Medium Link - Streams In Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/understanding-streams-in-flutter-dart-827340437da6)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried to do the following: selected.stream.listen((value) {
                print('Value from controller: $value');
              }); But I am having an error: Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to. Would you able to help me why is this happening?

Comment: There may be two reasons either you did not dispose/close the  stream or the listen method is calling multiple time in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rendomval = Fortune.randomInt(0, items.length); setState(() { selected.add(rendomval); }); print(rendomval);
```